# Calculus Book with Insane Problems or Techniques

Tags: calculus, integration, book-recommendation

Are there any books about Calculus, especially integration,

with insane problems with amazing approach?

Also, could you recommend me books for learning the integration techniques?

I want to learn more.

Comment: "Insane" and "amazing" are relative terms. When I was an undergrad student, most of what the professors did felt into this category. After (assisting in) teaching some of the same classes a few years later things look a little different.

Comment: Try "Inside interesting Integrals"

Comment: @Zach Is this book worth a look? Sounds interesting, but I am not into integrals that much, or integration theory. The preview of the book does not say much.

Comment: It's not very rigorous - It's more just the title, interesting integrals. You can find a pdf online if you would like to see what it's like.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers that have been posted, Richard?

Answer (score 2):

[*Inside Interesting Integrals* by Nahin.](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781493912766)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1186346)

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I disagree. The question asks for a reference, so the book title is already a complete answer. The link is just a bonus.

Comment: I completely agree that @Richard3141 has asked for a reference: however, the ones asking those questions benefit from a brief description of why the answerer likes the reference he gives. And this means giving a little guidance to them: this is the spirit of my review comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You might enjoy Boros and Moll, [Irresistible Integrals](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/irresistible-integrals/3C74C1BDE7A1D29028E5D9CB4607FF81) (link to publisher's page on the book).